# Google Maps Set LatLng Bounds with more than 2 inputs (not se,nw)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create boundaries for an LA map (let's call it 'losAngelesBoundaries') and I'd like to add more than 2 LatLng coordinates, since the map will NOT be a perfect square. Thus, using simply (sw,ne) coordinates will not work.

I know Google maps (for JS) wants me to do something like this:

```
var losAngelesBoundaries = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(swLat,swLng),
        new google.maps.LatLng(neLat,neLng)
);
```

But I'd like to create a custom map with several spots, like so:

```
var losAngelesBoundaries = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0],lng[0]),
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1],lng[1]),
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat[2],lng[2]),
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat[3],lng[3]),
        .........
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0],lng[0]),
);
```

Is there a 'polygon' function or something I can use to create Bounds to create a boundary with more than just 2 sets of coordinates?

Note - Needs to be for web/javascript. I see there's a way to do it on Android.

Comment: Just create a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shape/polygon on your map with more than 2 boundaries using javascript. Look at the [API guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons).

To work on your example:

Instead of calling

```
var losAngelesBoundaries = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

you can call

```
 var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
            {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
            {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

var losAngelesPolygon= new google.maps.Polygon({
           paths: triangleCoords,
           strokeColor: '#FF0000',
           strokeOpacity: 0.8,
           strokeWeight: 2,
           fillColor: '#FF0000',
           fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
```